# Windows 8 opens notepad on boot- no startup entry found

Tags: windows-8, notepad

I just upgraded from windows 7 to windows 8 and everything is working fine except notepad keeps opening on boot with a "access denied" window that comes up as well. I've ran MBAM and removed some junk, I've disabled every "file not found" item in autoruns as well as something that had a text/xml title in it and I've ran CCleaner a few times. Nothing is working, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Some text appears in notepad?

Comment: Something is starting it.  There is an entry.  have you tried to disable everything except the absolute required programs by hand?

Comment: No text, just a blank notepad

Comment: @Zach As it happens all the time, leave Notepad open, then start the Task Manager, and switch to the **Details** tab. Right-click the column header, and choose **Select columns** from the menu. Enable the **Command Line** option and click **OK**. Finally check the command line parameters associated to `notepad.exe`.

Comment: You could try dis-associating all file types with notepad as the default app ... Maybe reassign to notepad++ or word pad. This may tell you if the notepad is being launched specifically, or simply because windows is trying to open a text file.

Comment: Check Task Scheduler, it can cause things to run on boot or login.

Comment: OKay so the details pane shows the C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe followed by C:\Users\Zach\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Programs\Statup\desktop.ini

Is it Safe to delete the desktop.ini file from the startup folder?

Answer (score 1):

It was the desktop.ini file in the startup folder- deleting that cleared it up