# Notepad opens when starting computer

Tags: windows-10, notepad

since I have installed Windows 10 a notepad opens when I start up my computer and log in. It is empty and shows a Message-Box with the Message "Access Denied".

It happens every single time and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Edit: Thanks to the comments, I found that in the Startup-Folder there is a file called desktop.ini which seems to be the file that is getting opened. Can I delete it without breaking anything?

Comment: Check your "Start up" folder? Maybe it is trying to open a txt file (that it no longer has access to). Not sure if its the same location, but on Windows 8.1 it is on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp --- Note the ProgramData is a hidden folder.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Windows 8 opens notepad on boot- no startup entry found](http://superuser.com/q/729244)

Comment: @darius in Windows 8 and 10, you can use `shell:startup` as location which will correctly translate to the startup folder in your startmenu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden `desktop.ini` is present in Startup folders on a normal Windows installation. It's responsible for setting folder's localized name and icon. Deleting it is safe, but may not solve the problem. You can try to *move* it to a different folder *and rename it immediately* (otherwise funny things may happen). If it won't help, move it back and revert previous name.

#### How to pinpoint the cause of this problem

**Method 1.** When the "Access denied" message box is visible, *don't close it*. Instead, start [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/processexplorer?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and click the *Show process tree* button [image: "Show process tree" button]. Drag the crosshair button [image: Crosshair button] from Process Explorer's toolbar to the message box. Process that owns that window will be selected.

- Look at its direct parent. If you recognize it, then that app tries to open a protected file in Notepad.
- If parent process doesn't look familiar, right-click any column header and click *Select columns*, then check *Command line* and click OK. A new column will appear, extend it. It will show you arguments that were passed to Notepad, including file path. It may hint you which problematic file is being opened.

**Method 2.** Use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to view everything that's launched when Windows starts - not only *Startup* items from all locations (there's more than one *Startup* folder), but also *Run* key in registry, *RunOnce* entries, services, scheduled tasks, shell extensions and much more. Offending entry will most likely be found on the *Logon* tab, but you can also look at *Everything*. Just don't uncheck stuff unless you;re sure what you're doing, some of these are required for normal operation of Windows.